# Connection refused when trying to use rest over https

Tags: java, rest

I'm having trouble trying to use https rest on my remote server. I have a remote server deployed using jelastic that is working in https. Im going to host another server in jelastic that would act as the client.But when I try to run this code:

```
        String result;
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
            WebTarget target = client
                    .target("https://myresturi/Test");

            Invocation invocation = target.request().buildGet();
            Response response = invocation.invoke();

            result = (String) response.readEntity(new GenericType<String>() {});
```

I get :

```
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to mysecreturi:443 [mysecreturi/10.1.4.83] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:328)
at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:443)
at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:63)
at deployment.ROOT.ear.socio-logistico-web.war//laboratorio.tse.AutenticacionBean.autenticar(AutenticacionBean.java:36)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at javax.el.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:245)
at javax.el.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:338)
at javax.el.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:198)
at org.glassfish.jakarta.el@3.0.3.jbossorg-2//com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:110)
at org.glassfish.jakarta.el@3.0.3.jbossorg-2//com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:177)
at org.glassfish.jakarta.el@3.0.3.jbossorg-2//com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:183)
at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.14.SP01//com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.toString(ELText.java:205)
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.14.SP01//com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.toString(ELText.java:131)
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.14.SP01//com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.CommentInstruction.write(CommentInstruction.java:36)
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.14.SP01//com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:41)
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.14.SP01//com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:169)
at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP04//javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1650)
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.14.SP01//com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:468)
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.14.SP01//com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:170)
at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP04//javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:132)
at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP04//javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:132)
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.14.SP01//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:102)
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.14.SP01//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76)
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.14.SP01//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:199)
at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP04//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:708)
... 51 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to mysecreturi:443 [mysecreturi/10.1.4.83] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156)
at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:323)
... 80 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:289)
at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:368)
at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
```

What is weird is that if I try to run this code localy in ecliple it works fine, and if I try using https://reqbin.com/ it works fine as well. If I try using http instead of https it works remotely as well

Comment: 10.1.4.83 looks like a private ip, does the hostname resolve to that from outside Jelastic? Like on your local machine.